# AWS Lambda remove unwanted rows of text

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a text file which is dropped in to an s3 bucket **(bucket_name_1)**, I would like to use AWS Lambda to remove the unwanted headers and footers in the file and write it to another s3 bucket **(bucket_name_2)**.

Sample of the file:

```
UNWANTED HEADER

UNWANTED HEADER

Date|FirstName|Surname|Age|
1/21/2020|JOHN|SMITH|45|
1/21/2020|EMMA|BROWN|29|
1/21/2020|FRANK|WILSON|37|
...


UNWANTED FOOTER
```

So far I have a lambda which will read the file in

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket_name_1 = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    bucket_name_2 = 'output-bucket'
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']


    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name_1, key)

    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    print(body)
```

Comment: Hi, there are 2 unrelated questions here: (1) remove text from string (purely python question); (2) how to write text to s3 (boto3/aws). Have you researched each of them on their own? Because I suspect answers to both will be readily available on the internet. Certainly the AWS boto3 documentation should contain examples of writing to s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Download the file to `/tmp/` using [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)
- Manipulate the file, or copy the desired lines to an 'output file'
- Upload the resulting file to S3 using [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

It would be something like this:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    bucket_in = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    bucket_out = 'output-bucket'
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    filename_in = '/tmp/in.txt'
    filename_out = '/tmp/out.txt'

    # Download file
    s3_client.download_file(bucket_in, key, filename_in)

    # Remove headers and footers
    with open(filename_in, 'r') as file_in:
        with open(filename_out, 'w') as file_out:
            for line in file_in:
                # Put logic here for including/excluding lines from source file
                file_out.write(line)

    # Upload output file
    s3_client.upload_file(filename_out, bucket_out, key)
```